# How can a miner mine more than 3 XMR every day with one rig?

Tags: cpu-mining

Experts, I saw a miner on nanopool who can mine 3+ XMR every day using one rig. Can anyone tell me how this is possible? What kind of hardware might this miner be using! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It won't be one "rig", it would be either some entity using a proxy such as XMRigProxy or hashrate bought via somewhere such as NiceHash.